# How to show $\psi^*(x,-t)$ is also solution of the Schrodinger equation

Tags: calculus, physics, partial-derivative

I've seen it stated that it "can easily be seen" that if $\psi(r,t)$ is a solution of the Schrodinger equation : $ih \dfrac{\partial \psi(r,t)}{\partial t} = H \psi(r,t)$, then $\psi^*(r,-t)$ is also a solution.

But how can this be shown in detail? In particular, what is the partial derivative with respect to time of $\psi^*(r,-t)$? If I just apply the chain rule to $\psi^*(r,-t)\equiv conjugate(\psi(r,-t))$, then I get $\dfrac{\partial conjugate(\psi(r,-t))}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial conjugate}{\partial \psi} * \dfrac{\partial \psi(r,-t)}{\partial t}$. But what's the derivative of the "conjugate" function?

Comment: Consider
$
\psi(r,t) = u(r,t) + iv(r,t)
$
and then it should work out

Comment: The time derivative of the conjugate is the conjugate of the time derivative.

Comment: The key seems to be that $(H \psi(r,t))^* = H \psi^*(r,t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$
i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi(x,t)}{\partial t} = H \psi(x,t),
$$

whence

$$
\left( i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi(x,t)}{\partial t} \right)^* = \Big( H \psi(x,t) \Big)^*,
$$

so

$$
i^* \hbar \frac{\partial \psi^*(x,t)}{\partial t} = H \psi^*(x,t).
$$

As $i^* = -i$, we can write

$$
- i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi^*(x,t)}{\partial t} = H \psi^*(x,t),
$$

thus

$$
- i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi^*(x,-t)}{\partial [-t]} = H \psi^*(x,-t),
$$

yielding

$$
i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi^*(x,-t)}{\partial t} = H \psi^*(x,-t),
$$

so IF $\phi(x,t)$ is a solution, then $\phi^*(x,-t)$ is also a solution.